# UIImageview does not appear at position specified with UIImageview.center

Tags: swift, uiimageview, collision-detection

[image: Gif of the functionality which also shows the problem]

I made a simple app with Xcode in swift in which a circular Imageview in the middle of the screen can be moved with swipe-gesture and changes color when touching the outside of the bigger ring (image for reference) and at the same time changes location to the middle of the screen. Change of color and respawn is achieved by an if statement that changes the file of the picture when the euclidian distance between the middle-points of the smaller Imageview and the middle coordinates of the screen exceeds a certain length. However, when the Imageview spawns in what seems to me to be fixed middle coordinates, the spawning-position is slighty moved in the direction of the swipe. And even more so if the swipe-gesture is faster. Thanks for any hints.

---

Edit: I removed every part that keeps this from being a minimal example for the problem I have and also uploaded the files I for the colored balls. Can anyone tell me how else I could improve my question to get an answer?

---

Edit: Now I added an animated gif which firstly shows the functionality and later, when I increase dragging speed, also shows the problem that I'm facing.

[image: File for colored ball. (1.png)][image: File for colored ball. (2.png)][image: File for colored ball. (3.png)]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var colorImg: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func panMade(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
                let translation = sender.translation(in: sender.view)
                let changeX = (sender.view?.center.x)! + translation.x
                let changeY = (sender.view?.center.y)! + translation.y
                sender.view?.center = CGPoint(x: changeX, y: changeY)
                sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: sender.view)
        }

        let coordX = colorImg.frame.origin.x+60
        let coordY = colorImg.frame.origin.y+60
        let centerX = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width*0.5
        let centerY = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height*0.5
        let a = (coordX-centerX) ; let b = (coordY-centerY) ; let c = (a*a) ; let d = (b*b) ; let j = Double(c+d)

        if (j.squareRoot() > 112) {
            let n = Int.random(in: 1..<4)
            colorImg.image = UIImage(named: String(n) + ".png")
            sleep(1)
            colorImg.center = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I removed every part that keeps this from being a minimal example for the problem I have and also uploaded the files I for the colored balls." Not really. The minimal example would show what the problem is with _just the drag_. You don't need the color change to show the issue you're asking about. So it would be really good if you would get rid of all of that.

Comment: Also, your code makes no sense, as you appear to be calling code inside `panMade` _not_ in any `sender.state`. Plus, you need to cover every possible `state`. Plus, never never never never say `sleep`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I took the code for moving an Imageview from some tutorial since I didn't know how to do it as this is literally the first time I'm using swift / xcode, so I'm probably lacking understanding of how exactly it works. Do you have any suggestion on where I could look to find better directions on moving objects that will fit my purpose?

Comment: The problem for me is that I don't see any problem with the code being used simply for the drag, and I don't see any problem with it in your gif either. That is why I asked you to isolate the issue. As I said, it is the _extra_ code, the color changing code, that is getting in your way as far as I can see. That code is completely bogus, since it takes place no matter what stage of the drag we are on.

Comment: Regarding the color changing making no sense, that would be taken care of by putting the code inside the if sender... statement, right? And now that I tried to create a minimal example by following your instructions being only left with dragging one object, I think I have found the problem. When the if (j.squareRoot() > 112) statement comes into play and the coordinates are set to center, the dragging motion from before keeps moving the object even after the spawn. So I would need some command to stop registering the swiping until lifting the finger and touching again. Makes any sense?

Comment: Not to me. Just make the body of the method consist of a `switch` on `sender.state` and nothing else. Cover every case. Do what you want to do _in some state_. It makes no sense to interrupt the gesture at `begin` or `changed` by grabbing the image view out of the user's hand and sticking it somewhere. But that is what you are doing.

Comment: @matt I achieved what I wanted by putting sender.isEnabled = false ; sender.isEnabled = true after the second if statement. But only because I tried to reduce it to just the drag as you suggested, so thanks for that. Could you tell me why I souldn't use sleep and what would be an alternative? Used it in python a lot...